# Iteration through none type array

Tags: python, opencv

im new to python, so hear is my problem.
I'm using hough line transform to detect objects trough a webcam feed.

At first i used static images and that worked fine but now im trying with a live video feed and the program keeps crashing.

```
base = cv2.HoughLinesP(vertical, 1, np.pi / 180, 80, minLineLength=50, maxLineGap=75)

    for line in base:
        try:
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
            if intersect < y2:
                cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        except:
            continue
```

This part of de code is where the error point to.
I dont understand how i can make the line array (or apparently list in python?) of a certain type.

the full error is this:

```
  File "C:/Users/ShadowTwins/Documents/GitHub/Detection-algorithm/main.py", line 92, in <module>
    img = process(img)
  File "C:/Users/ShadowTwins/Documents/GitHub/Detection-algorithm/main.py", line 60, in process
    line = np.array()
TypeError: array() missing required argument 'object' (pos 1)
[ WARN:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (436) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

I know that if it doesn't find any lines the code breaks, thats why i put the try/execpt lines there.
but i expect the code doesnt reach that far before the error.

I'm close to just make it all into C++, would this be a better option in the future or if the program get more advanced? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reproduce the problem, I placed my hand on the webcam.

The problem occurs when `base` variable is `None`.

[image]

Therefore just check if `base` is not None, then display:

```py
if base is not None:
    for line in base:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
        if intersect < y2:
            cv2.line(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
```

my output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the problem.

Comment: Glad, if I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a numpy array, you do not pass any arguments to `np.array()`.
What you can do is `line = np.array(0)` which will create empty numpy array

Comment: Where do I put it in the code? No matter where i put it it doesnt change anything

Comment: @ShadowTwins I believe you declare the `line` on line 60 since this is what error says

Comment: > for line in base:
that is the line that generate the error